# Span submit button to col-xs-12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can some one help me how I can get the submitbutton spanning longer in mobile device ? Please see images.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Account Deatils</h3></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        tetsing
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to add image as it seems an issue in stackoverflow website.

Comment: I have tried add button under col-xs-13 div but still appears small button on mobile. I want to span the whole row in mobile devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Bootsrap you could add the class 'form-control' to your button. Couldn't honestly tell you if that's up to Bootstrap's specification or best practice - if not, you could create a new class and add in:

```
display:block;
width:100%;
```

That said, Bootstrap column's by default do have some padding, so this wouldn't be truly 100% of the window; if you wanted that you could create either a class called noPadding to add to the column div or just use the row as the proper container.

Comment: Hello, I am learning bootstartp and jquery and trying to create a prototype. I have couple of question what I have created so far I am hoping you could help on this.  
   Please refer jsfiddle for my questions.  
1. Why blue color panel is not showing on JSFiddle ? I have added bootstrap. css and bootstrap.js as external resources. I can see in my local server but not on JSFiddle sample. 2. Why all my form fields are below labels? 3. Why all form fields are left justified though the panel was spanned to the entire col-xs-12. 4.

Comment: If I view the page in responsiveness, it looks great in all devises. Exct last submit button is still showing it as small original size. Is there anyway I can span submit button in mobile and tablet devises bigger? Like spanning from left to right of the devise?

Comment: I combined your fiddle with another user's Bootstrap fiddle which can be found here - http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/1/
Anywho, as for question 1 the blue color was most likely not showing due to a problem with loading the external file - it looks right in your fiddle glancing at it but that's a non-issue. Perhaps a missing theme.css? As for question 2 by default Bootstrap places fields below labels, a way around that would be to use form-inline per Bootstrap spec. Lastly, your form fields are left justified even though the column is 12 because there's no divs wrapping the form fields.

Comment: Also, if you remove the input-group class from your inputs they will be 100%; I believe input-groups are used in conjunction with spans to add gylphicons with Bootstrap. To see the button full width using the form-control class you can go here : http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/3/

Comment: Thank you verymuch for your explination. May i ask you small help on updating the jsfiddle for adding DIV for form filds to be center instead of left justified?

Comment: I have added a table inside a panel. I see row borders, i added below code for removing it but still not working..table tr, .table td {
    border: none;
}

Comment: Well, you may need two classes - one to define the desired width of the inputs because Bootstrap gives all form-controls a width:100%. A second class would be needed to actual center the controls. As seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/4/

Comment: For your table question I'm not entirely sure - can you fork or update the fiddle with the issue recreated? Unless you mean the top and bottom row borders on the table cells;
.table > thead > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td{ border-top:0px;} (or if you're targeting directly you can do td{border:0px !important} but that's bad practice.

Comment: Hi, Can you help me to keep Expiration dorpdowns as in-line? I have tried "form-group-in-line". Tw othings happening.1.CVV field also geting moved to the same line of Month and Year. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Here is my fina lversion. Than kyou very muc hfor your help. It looks great except I am not able to adjust Expiration label. Thanks!http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/6/. View the page in full screen. It also looks great in responsiveness.

Comment: There was no CSS for 'form-group-inline'; so I added that and display:inline-block. You can see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/7/ . However it breaks the flow of the form. To fix this you can further edit the CSS as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/9/.  Another solution can be seen here which involved changing some of the HTML to use different column sizes and using a custom label class - http://jsfiddle.net/5WwTB/8/

Comment: Hi I am back again :). This is a basic question. I am using bootstrap and custome jquery UI.How can I control or change the default FONT ? I am reading some article about awesomefont glyphicons etc.Any help please? Thanks!